# Java Matrix doesn't prints last row

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix

```
package com.test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Rows = ?");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
            int nrows = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Columns = ?");
            if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int ncolumns = sc.nextInt();
                char matrix[][] = new char[nrows][ncolumns];
                System.out.println("Enter matrix");
                for (int row = 0; sc.hasNextLine() && nrows > row; row++) {
                        matrix[row] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
                }
                for (int row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
                    for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
                        System.out.print(matrix[row][column] + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my programm reads matrix and prints it, but the last row doesn't prints. I think, that problem in for-loop, which prints columns.

Input:

```
2
2
-=
=-
```

Actual output:

```
-=
```

Expected output:

```
-=
=-
```

Comment: Can you post the input, actual output, and expected output?  It may be that you aren't filling your variables correctly in the first `for` loop.

Comment: Are you sure that this code `matrix[row] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();` does what you want? What were you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Pshemo yeap, i'm sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
for (int row = 0; sc.hasNextLine() && nrows > row; row++) {
        matrix[row] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
}
```

to

```
sc.nextLine();
for (int row = 0; nrows > row; row++) {
        matrix[row] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
}
```

Main problem is that `nextInt()`, or other `nextXXX()` methods except `nextLine()` do not consume line separators, which means that when you input `2` (and press enter) actual input will look like `2\n` or `2\r\n` or `2\r` depending on OS.

So with `nextInt` you are reading only value `2` but Scanner's cursor will be set before line separators like

```
2|\r\n
 ^-----cursor
```

which will make `nextLine()` return empty String, because there ware no characters between cursor and next line separators.

So to actually read line after `nextInt` (not the empty string) you need to add another `nextLine()` to set cursor after these line separators.

```
2\r\n|
     ^-----cursor - nextLine() will return characters from here 
                    till next line separators or end of stream
```

---

BTW to avoid this problem you can use

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

instead of `int i = nextInt()`.

Comment: the nextInt() will NOT consume the newline character, you need a nextLine to do that.